# Updating a Windows Phone App using a new project

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I uploaded a Windows Phone application to the Windows Phone Store 1 year ago.

I want to update the application, but I've lost my code.

I don't know the package name of the App.

Will the Windows phone app store allow updates for apps created from other packages/projects?

Do they check whether the name .xap files match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't look for same name of the `.xap` file. In WP dashboard, you can click on update app and uplaod new `.xap`. It wouldn't matter if source code is same or not. So, you can create new project/solution in VS and upload new `.xap`.

Basically, it is your app and if it follows guidelines specified by WP team then you can change source code as you like and upload `.xap` for the same app.

Comment: To update i need to update the old project or i can create a completely new project

Comment: You can create new project. Edited answer accordingly :)

Comment: In android you need to sign your app with same keystore for update, does Windows Phones have no such mechanism

Comment: Nope. Uploading `.xap` would do it in windows phone. If you are using some 3rd party API keys, that you might have to configure it correctly.